# Box Shadow Transition Not Working

Tags: jquery, transition, mouseenter, box-shadow

So, I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, but it works in CSS if I code it that way. However, I decided to challenge myself to see if I can figure it out in JQuery since I'm new to it. Unfortunately, for some reason it's not working. I've researched for a very long time, and I don't know why it's not working.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="adventure.css"/>
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="adventure.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Adventure Corner</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="panel-holder">
        <div id="nav-holder"> 
            <div class="nav-button"><a href="#">HOME</a></div>
            <div class="nav-button"><a href="#">NORTH AMERICA</a></div>
            <div class="nav-button"><a href="#">SOUTH AMERICA</a></div>
            <div class="nav-button"><a href="#">ASIA</a></div>
            <div class="nav-button"><a href="#">AUSTRALIA</a></div>
            <div class="nav-button"><a href="#">EUROPE</a></div>
            <div class="nav-button"><a href="#">AFRICA</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#nav-holder {
    margin-top: 200px;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

#nav-holder li {
    list-style: none;
}

#nav-holder a {
    color: floralwhite;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    background-color: red;
    border-bottom: solid black .5px;
}

.nav-button {
     box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 orange;
}
```

JQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#nav-holder a").each(function(){
        $(this).mouseenter(function(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();

            $(".nav-button").css({
                transition: "ease-in-out .2s",
                "-webkit-transition":  "ease-in-out .3s",
                boxShadow: "inset 300px 0 0 0 orange",
                "-webkit-backface-visibility": "hidden",
                "-webkit-transform": "scale(1)"
            });
        });

        $("#nav-holder a").mouseout(function () {
            $(".nav-button").css({
                boxShadow: "inset 0 0 0 0 orange"
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Your code works fine. Have you an error in console? or paste your html and all js

Comment: I edited it to include my other code as well.

Comment: Oh, and I do not have any console errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your `background-color:red` in `nav-holder` and move this in `nav-button.` and replace:

```
$(".nav-button").css({
```

by

```
$(this).closest(".nav-button").css({
```

Try below:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#nav-holder a").each(function(){
        $(this).mouseenter(function(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();

            $(this).closest(".nav-button").css({
                transition: "ease-in-out .2s",
                "-webkit-transition":  "ease-in-out .3s",
                boxShadow: "inset 300px 0 0 0 orange",
                "-webkit-backface-visibility": "hidden",
                "-webkit-transform": "scale(1)"
            });
        });

        $("#nav-holder a").mouseout(function () {
            $(".nav-button").css({
                boxShadow: "inset 0 0 0 0 orange"
            });
        });
    });
});
```

```css
#nav-holder {
    margin-top: 200px;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

#nav-holder li {
    list-style: none;
}

#nav-holder a {
    color: floralwhite;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    border-bottom: solid black .5px;
}

.nav-button {
     box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 orange;
     background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panel-holder">
    <div id="nav-holder"> 
        <div class="nav-button"><a href="#">HOME</a></div>
        <div class="nav-button"><a href="#">NORTH AMERICA</a></div>
        <div class="nav-button"><a href="#">SOUTH AMERICA</a></div>
        <div class="nav-button"><a href="#">ASIA</a></div>
        <div class="nav-button"><a href="#">AUSTRALIA</a></div>
        <div class="nav-button"><a href="#">EUROPE</a></div>
        <div class="nav-button"><a href="#">AFRICA</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hm. This seems to have fixed it, but unfortunately it is flashing and glitching whenever its animation is running now. I have never ran into this issue before, and the code I had on it before worked,

Comment: ?? i have no blink and glitching.

Comment: It only does it in Chrome. :/

Comment: It's fine on chrome for me! i dont know what is your issue because i have no blinking and glitching

Comment: Hm. Might be a plug-in or something I have for it then. Either way, thanks for your help!